# jOOQ: how can I view a field which has been aliased?

Tags: java, scala, jooq

I've been playing around with jOOQ (in Scala) and would appreciate an answer to the (seemingly simple) question: *how can I view a field which has been aliased?*

Hopefully the following example illustrates my problem:

```
import org.jooq.impl._
import org.jooq.impl.DSL._

val a = field("a", SQLDataType.DOUBLE)
val b = a.as("b")

// prints "b" 
println(b)

// however, I would like it to print a "b" as in
select(b)
```

#### Edit:

I have found a case where the answer provided by @Lukas Eder doesn't work. A modified answer of the one below for which the following case works would be much appreciated (cheers):

```
val f = field("amount", SQLDataType.DOUBLE)
val p = field("partition", SQLDataType.INTEGER)
val o = field("order_by", SQLDataType.DATE)

// prints as expected
val r = coalesce(sum(f).over().partitionBy(p).orderBy(o), 0)

// coalesce(
//   sum(amount) over (partition by partition order by order_by asc), 
//   0)

val a = r.as("test")

// question mark instead of 0
println(
  DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
   .renderContext()
   .declareFields(true)
   .render(a)
)

//  coalesce(sum(amount) over (partition by partition order by order_by asc), ?) as "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

The "normal" way to generate SQL for an aliased field is the way you've seen. The way the field is referenced, e.g. when put in the `ORDER BY` clause.

The "exceptional" way to generate SQL for an aliased field is when it is placed in the `SELECT` clause, i.e. when it declares itself.

All [`QueryPart.toString()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/QueryPart.html) implementations generate the "normal" SQL string. If you explicitly want to generate the field declaration as in a `SELECT` clause, you can use [jOOQ's rendering API](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/sql-rendering/) directly:

```
println(
  DSL.using(SQLDialect.ORACLE)
     .renderContext()
     .declareFields(true)
     .render(b)
)
```